# JQuery Validate - ignoring the required rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with a number of inputs that are validated by jquery validate.

I need to validate this form in two different ways - when the form is submitted and when the form is saved. These two actions have different requirements. When the form is submitted validate needs to check that all required fields are completed. However when the form is saved, I would like it to ignore the required rules, whilst still checking other rules (maxLength/number/email etc).

I have found the ignore aspect of jquery. Can this be added / removed ? If so, can it be used to target only the required rule? e.g. field has rules: required: true, maxlength: 100 . Field is still checked for maxlength but required is ignored.

Comment: You should show your code so that we can answer this properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *only* way to *toggle* rules dynamically is through [the `.rules('add')` and `.rules('remove')` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) provided by the plugin.

Since you didn't show code, I can only show generic examples:

Remove `required` rule from the `input` with `name="myfield"`…

```
$('input[name="myfield"]').rules('remove', 'required');
```

Remove `required` rule from all `input` elements that are `type="text"`.  Multiple elements require the `.each()` method…

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('remove', 'required');
});
```

Adding rules dynamically is a similar process.

```
$('input[name="myfield"]').rules('add', {
    required: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry for not providing code - thought my explanation would suffice. Anyway, I have added a class to all inputs that need "required" toggled and used your solution to loop through them to add and remove as required. Thank you.

Comment: @Robin - Of course `rules()` is still part of the plugin and my answer is still relevant to the question.  **PHP version has nothing to do with this** - a JavaScript/jQuery issue.  Also, if you're getting that error, then you likely did not properly include the library or the plugin into your project.

Comment: @Robin, then you did something wrong.  You will have to post a question where you show us exactly what you tried.